# Python Coding in Blender

Tags: python-3.x, blender, mysql5, mysql-5.0

can someone help me solve this problem?

I'm using Blender 2.74 and Python 3.4 with the correct connector for MySQL. (By the way, I'm just a beginner in using Blender and Python.)

What I want is to make a login UI and save the inputted name into the database, but my code seems a bit off or wrong. When I try to run the code, it didn't save the value in the variable, but when i try to run it in python IDE (PyCharm) it worked.

Here's the code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:\Python34\DLLs')

import mysql.connector

import bge
bge.render.showMouse(1)

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

sensor = cont.sensors ["enter"]
pname = own.get("prpText")

enter = cont.sensors ["enter"]
numpadenter = cont.sensors ["numpadenter"]

if enter.positive or numpadenter.positive:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='dbname')

    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tblname VALUE(%s", (pname))

#this are the other codes that i have tried so far:
#add_player = ("INSERT INTO storymode " "(PlayerName) " "VALUES (%s)")
#data_player = (pname)
#cursor.execute(add_player, data_player)

#cursor.execute("INSERT INTO storymode" "(PlayerName)" "VALUES (%(pname)s)")

db.commit()

db.close()
```

The Error is:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1.

Can someone tell what i need to do here? Do I need some add-ons for it to work?

Thank you very much for reading my post and for the people who will give their opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis and an 'S' in you're sql INSERT statement?

```
INSERT INTO tblname VALUE (%s
```

needs to be

```
INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (%s)
```

Comment: I tried it after %s but a new error popped up, and now its a syntax error

Comment: Oh I think it should be VALUES with an 'S'

Comment: I already tried that but nothing's change, there's still an error.

Comment: Is there other ways for saving data in mysql?

Comment: Try this: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tblname VALUES (?)", pname)`

Comment: Still have an error: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version (My SQL server version is 5.0) for the right the syntax to use near '?)' at line 1.

Comment: I tried another code:      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO storymode VALUES({})" .format(pname))    and when I run the code, it has an error saying: Unknown column 'the inputted value' in 'field list'